# How to use material design with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, material-design

I was really amazed by the look and feel of google's material design. I googled on how to integrate it in a rails application and I came across this gem called

```
'material_design_lite-rails'
```

Can someone please give me an example on how to use this gem as I am completely new to Material Design. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Material Design Lite**

1. Installation Add ‘gem material_design_lite-sass’ to your Gemfile.
2. Run ‘bundle install’.
3. Add ‘//= require material’ to your app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
4. Add ‘@import “material”;’ to your app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss.

---

***RESOURCES:***

[Medium - Material Design Lite - Rails - Tutorial](https://medium.com/@vonchristian/how-to-use-material-design-lite-with-rails-9d96d01369e4#.jz48s1xad)

[Material Design Lite - Sass - Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/material_design_lite-sass)

[Material Design Lite - Components - Examples](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

there is a tool that you can actually use. in your gemfile add the following code

```
 source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-materialize'
 end
```

then head to the application.js file in app/assets/javascript/application.js, just below requiring jquery

```
//= require materialize
```

after that include the following in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
*= require materialize
```

that should do the trick :)

Comment: can u also give me an example of it. I mean could you make a floating form or button in material design and show me the code